# DataTable DOM id value changes beyond 10th record

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatable, datatables

I have a DataTable that displays the actual record ID number on the first column which I named "#" for simplicity.  I've added an anchor tag to this column so I can open a popup modal with more detailed data this:

```
<a href=\"#\" id=\"RECORDEDIT____" + rec.Seq.ToString() + "\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#my_popup\" + ">" + rec.Seq.ToString() + "</a>
```

For the first 10 records, it works fine; the popup displays the correct "ID" of the clicked element.  However if I go any page beyond the first page and click any record there, I get the record of the PREVIOUSLY clicked element.  For example if I previously clicked record #7 and then click record 12 on page 2, I get record 7 details.  If I click record 15 on page 2, I still get record 7 details.

To get the correct value, I've tried:

```
$('*[id^=RECORDEDIT____]').click(function () {
            var indexValue = $(this).attr("id");  <--- Here
            var data = indexValue;
            .....
            $(".modal-body").html(data);
        });

$('*[id^=RECORDEDIT____]').click(function () {
                var indexValue = $(this).attr("data-id");  <--- Here (added the "data-id" attribute first, of course)
                var data = indexValue;
                .....
                $(".modal-body").html(data);
            });

$('*[id^=RECORDEDIT____]').click(function () {
                var indexValue = $(this).html();  <--- Here
                var data = indexValue;
                .....
                $(".modal-body").html(data);
            });

$('*[id^=RECORDEDIT____]').click(function () {
                var indexValue = $(this).text();  <--- Here
                var data = indexValue;
                .....
                $(".modal-body").html(data);
            });
```

Is this the normal behavior of datatables?  Can this be corrected?

Comment: Can you add a snippet.??

Comment: use a delegated eventhandler -> `$('body').on('click', '*[id^=RECORDEDIT____]', function() {` ...I guess the duplicate and the fact the click is responded to, is caused by your use of selector wildcards. Links for page #2 ... is certainly NEVER handled.

Comment: This worked for me but why can't I choose this as the correct answer????